# In rust, convert a string representation of an octal into a u32

Tags: rust, integer, data-conversion, octal

I'm using the following code to convert a string representation of an octal into a `u32`:

```rust
pub fn umask() -> String {
    match env::var("UMASK") {
        Ok(res) => res.into(),
        _ => "777".into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:#?}", u32::from_str_radix(format!("0o{}", umask()).as_str(), 8));
}
```

Instead all I Get is:

```
Err(
    ParseIntError {
        kind: InvalidDigit,
    },
)
```

According to [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Octal.html) it looks like it's in the correct format and as it's an octal, it's base 8 thus a radix of 8 is what you need.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `0o` prefix. `from_str_radix` does not expect any kind of a prefix, as the radix is already given as a separate argument.

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("{}", u32::from_str_radix("777", 8)?); // Prints: 511
    println!("{}", u32::from_str_radix("0777", 8)?); // Prints: 511
    Ok(())
}
```